# wrap spring bean with another bean

Tags: java, spring

I have some service bean which is accessible by identifier `someSpecificService` which I need to modify.
Beans are defined in different xml files and are collected together in runtime. So one big xml file is created where all these xmls are imported:

```
context.xml
....
<import path="spring1.xml" />
<import path="spring2.xml" />
...
```

So there is following configuration:

```
<-- definitions from spring1.xml -->
<alias name="defaultSomeSpecificService" alias="someSpecificService" />
<bean id="defaultSomeSpecificService" class="..."/>
....
<!-- definitions from spring2.xml -->
<alias name="myOwnSomeSpecificService" alias="someSpecificService" />
<bean id="myOwnSomeSpecificService" class="..." /> <!-- how to inject previously defined someSpecificService into this new bean? -->
```

I would like to override `someSpecificService` from `spring1.xml` in `spring2.xml`, however I do need to inject previously defined bean `defaultSomeSpecificService` and all I know is its alias name `someSpecificService` which I need to redefine to new bean `myOwnSomeSpecificService`.

Is it possible to implement?

Comment: I'm confused about your use case. You say `I do need to inject previously defined bean defaultSomeSpecificService`. So you need to inject that bean, but also name a different bean in `spring2.xml` to the same name `someSpecificService`? How do you load these configs?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, for the first question yes. For the second, I am not really sure because that code is inside third party framework, probably it calls `org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.setConfigLocations(String[])` with all xml configurations.

Comment: But you're sure that `spring2` has access to `spring1`? Either through a parent-child relationship or through `import`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, yes these both xmls are merged into a single context, like if they are all imported into single xml file

Comment: Don't want to sound condescending, but do you have any "decent" reason you'd want to overwrite the bean definition? Perhaps the problem can be overcome in a simpler, different way

Comment: @Grove, I want to be able to inherit beans. So I have some bean that implements some interface and is visible by alias `someService`, I need to modify its functionality, I make another bean that implements same interface, but I need to wrap existing bean `someService` in my new bean and register my new bean with same identifier (`someService`).

Comment: @Grove, I am not able to modify first bean definition. That is why I need this all fuss.

Comment: Basically you need to import the beans from the `spring1.xml`, but you'd like to shadow that particular bean with your implementation, correct? I take it not importing that xml is not an option.

Comment: @Grove, yes. I am neither able to avoid spring1.xml being imported nor to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to avoid trying to override the definition, by [creating a proxy for the service implementation to intercept all calls](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop-api.html) towards it.

1)  For the sake of the example, suppose the service would be something like:

```
public interface Service {
    public String run();
}

public class ExistingServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Override
    public String run() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Muahahahaha!");
    }
}
```

2)  Implement an interceptor instead of `myOwnSomeSpecificService`:

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

public class SomeSpecificServiceInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        String status;
        try {
            // allow the original invocation to actually execute
            status = String.valueOf(invocation.proceed());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println("Existing service threw the following exception [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
            status = "FAIL";
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

3) In `spring2.xml` define the proxy creator and the interceptor:

```
<bean id="serviceInterceptor" class="com.nsn.SomeSpecificServiceInterceptor" />

<bean id="proxyCreator" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
    <property name="beanNames" value="someSpecificService"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>serviceInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

4) Running a small example such as:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Service service = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml").getBean("someSpecificService", Service.class);
        System.out.println("Service execution status [" + service.run() + "]");
    }
}
```

... instead of the `IllegalStateException` stacktrace you'd normally expect, it will print:

```
Existing service threw the following exception [Muahahahaha!]
Service execution status [FAIL]
```

Please note that in this example the service instance is not injected in the interceptor as you asked because I had no user for it. However should you really need it, you can easily inject it via constructor/property/etc because the interceptor is a spring bean itself.